# Representation Atomic part of $C^*$-algebra

Tags: representation-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

If $\mathcal{A}$ is a $C^*$-Algebra, $\hat{\mathcal{A}}=spec(\mathcal{A})$, $(H_b,\pi_b)$ is any irreducible representation in equivalence class of $b$.   I want to know where can i find proof of these theorems.

1. $ \zeta : \mathcal{A} \rightarrow z \mathcal{A}^{**},~~ a\rightarrow z\bar{a}$

where $\bar{a}$ is an image of $a \in \mathcal{A}$ by natural embedding  of $\mathcal{A}$ in it's second dual and $z$ is central projection in $\mathcal{A}^{**}$. Prove that  $ \zeta$ is $C^*$-injective

---

$\mathsf{Z} :z \mathcal{A}^{**} \rightarrow \prod_{b~ \in \mathcal{\hat{A}}} B(H_b),~~~ \mathsf{Z}(a)= \prod _{b~ \in \mathcal{\hat{A}}} (\pi^{**} _b(a))$.

Where $\pi^{**} _b$ is $\sigma$-weak extension of $\pi_b$ to  $\mathcal{A}^{**}$. Prove that $\mathsf{Z}$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: You wrote two functions. What's the question?

Comment: @MartinArgerami I want to find proofs of these two theorems. I looked in C*-ALGEBRAS AND THEIR AUTOMORPHISM GROUPS but i didn't find them

Comment: I still see no theorems in what you wrote, sorry.

Comment: Sorry i fixed it